# Adding a column to Google Sheet changes the output of a cell in a different sheet without intending to

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering, offset

I have a Google Spreadsheet. It has three sheets in it: `Adoption Centers`, `Cats`, and `Rescue Pets`.

Rescue Pets is animal adoption center. Animals of different kinds are housed in it. Rows in 'Rescue Pets' provide data on these animals. Row 1 (`A1:F1`) looks like:

**Mater / 9 years old / Siamese / is good with kids / FALSE / TRUE**

where "/" represents a break in column, with formatting written as:

- NAME - Column A
- AGE - Column B
- SPECIES - Column C
- NOTES - Column D
- DOG? - Column E
- CAT? - Column F

The 'Adoption Centers' sheet provides a list of all the adoption centers used in this analysis. The text "Rescue Pets" is in cell A1 of the 'Adoption Centers' list.

Back to the 'Rescue Pets' *sheet*. Row 2 (`A2:F2`) of the 'Rescue Pets' sheet contains:

**Hunter / 2 years old / corgi / can't drink milk / TRUE / FALSE**.

Row 3 (`A3:F3`) of the 'Rescue Pets' sheet:

**Casper / 4 years old / tabby / previous liver disease / FALSE / TRUE**.

Now, the 'Cats' sheet filters data from the rows in the 'Rescue Pets' sheet with a TRUE boolean in the CAT column. I do this with the following line (written in cell A1 of the 'Cats' sheet):

`=FILTER(INDIRECT('Adoption Centers'!A1&"!A1:D3"),INDIRECT('Adoption Centers'!A1&"!F1:F3")=True)`

*The Problem:* I want to add a new column of data (Adoption Cost) to the 'Rescue Pets' sheet. I want to place this column between Column C (Species) and Column D (Notes) so that each row in the 'Rescue Pets' sheet now looks something like this:

Row 1 (`A1:G1`): **Mater / 9 years old / Siamese / $100 / is good with kids / FALSE / TRUE**,

Row 2 (`A2:G2`): **Hunter / 2 years old / corgi / $300 / can't drink milk / TRUE / FALSE**,

Row 3 (`A3:G3`): **Casper / 4 years old / tabby / $150 / previous liver disease / FALSE / TRUE**.

*The Question:* is there any way to change

`=FILTER(INDIRECT('Adoption Centers'!A1&"!A1:D3"),INDIRECT('Adoption Centers'!A1&"!F1:F3")=True)`

from cell A1 of the 'Cats' sheet so that, without having to explicitly go in and edit the references made to `D3` and `F1:F3` respectively to `E3` and `G1:G3`, it can still filter the 'Rescue Pets' sheet for all its data on adoptable cats?

Comment: Please extract from your real problem a sample situation that represents your concrete problem, provide input, output and what your are trying to achieve. Remove any information not related to the specific sample no other context is needed just how to solve a specific problem in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function is basically not built at all the way it should be (even though it works). It's referenceing a different sheet to then get a different sheet. It can be simplified considerably to just be:

```
=filter('Rescue Pets'!A:D,'Rescue Pets'!F:F=true)
```

TO account for the new costs column, you should be fine to INSERT a new column (not copy paste over your data) as it it will dynmically update.  Or you could just rewrite your formula to expand the full area as shown below:

```
=filter('Rescue Pets'!A:E,'Rescue Pets'!F:F=true)
```

Comment: The reason I reference 'Adoption Centers' is because I am actually working with more adoption centers than just Rescue Pets!

I have 'Rescue Pets', 'The Orphanage', 'Lost Cats', ... and 20 other adoption centers.  Since they all have different names, I figured the easiest way to change the filtering options between spreadsheets was to come up with

`=FILTER(INDIRECT('Adoption Centers'!A1&"!A1:D3"),INDIRECT('Adoption Centers'!A1&"!F1:F3")=True)`

and change only the 'A1' ("Rescue Pets") to 'A2' ("The Orphanage") and then 'A3' ("Lost Cats"), etc. all the way down.

Comment: And unfortunately, the ```INDIRECT``` function does not appear to be dynamic!

Comment: Indirect is not dynamic, which is why you shouldn't be using it with Filter.  There's a dozen different ways you could handle your issue more efficiently. However the most obvious answer is just update your filter function for each spreadsheet.  It's not that hard to write a formula and just select some columns in a different sheet. You don't need to type it out. You could also do named ranges, or combine all of your data to one tab with a column for which center. Regardless, I did answer the question you presented and I don't have any more time to invest in this.